# SQL Statement that Subs 0 for no Results

Tags: sql

I am having an issue getting the results I want from my SQL statement. I know I'm probably missing something simple but I just can't see it.

Here are my tables.

```
Table: Users (RoleID is linked to ID in Roles Table)
ID,   FirstName,   LastName,   RoleID 
1,    Matt,        Ryan,       1
2,    Chipper,     Jones,      1
3,    Julio,       Jones,      2
4,    Jason,       Bourn,      3

Table: Roles
ID,    Name
1,     Field Rep
2,     Tech
3,     Admin

Table: FRrequests (UserID is linked to ID in Users table) 
ID,   UserID,    Status
1,    1,         Open
2,    1,         Submitted
3,    1,         Delayed
4,    1,         Complete
```

What I want is an SQL statement that shows me a count of all the "Submitted" & "Delayed" requests for all the Field Reps. Below is an example of desired results.

```
Name             Count
Chipper Jones    0
Matt Ryan        2
```

Here is the statement I have so far and the results it gives me.

```
SELECT Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS Name, COUNT(FRrequests.ID) AS 'Open Requests'
FROM Users INNER JOIN
          Roles ON Users.RoleID = Roles.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
          FRrequests ON Users.ID = FRrequests.UserID
WHERE (Roles.Name = N'Field Rep') AND (FRrequests.Status = 'Submitted' OR FRrequests.Status = 'Delayed')
GROUP BY Users.FirstName, Users.LastName

Name             Count
Matt Ryan        2
```

I know that the "AND (FRrequests.Status = 'Submitted' OR FRrequests.Status = 'Delayed')" part is what is breaking it. If I run it without that in the statement I get all the users but it counts all status not just submitted and delayed. I just can't figure out what I'm missing to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, try the following:

```
SELECT U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS Name, COUNT(F.ID) AS 'Open Requests'
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Roles R
    ON U.RoleID = R.ID 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM FRrequests 
            WHERE Status IN ('Submitted','Delayed')) F
    ON U.ID = F.UserID
WHERE R.Name = N'Field Rep' 
GROUP BY U.FirstName, U.LastName
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for the help and what a fast response time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a row for each Field Rep if you wish to include Field Reps that have no requests. Therefore you need to use a left outer join along the following lines:

```
SELECT 
    u.FirstName || ' ' || u.LastName as Name 
    , COALESCE(frr.Counter,0) as Count 
FROM 
    Users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
            UserID 
            ,count(*) as Counter 
        FROM 
            FRrequests 
        WHERE 
            Status IN ('Submitted', 'Delayed') 
        GROUP BY
            UserID
    ) frr ON frr.UserID = u.ID 
    , Roles r 
WHERE 
    u.ID = f.UserID 
    AND u.RoleID = r.ID 
    AND r.Name = 'Field Rep' 
;
```

A left outer join will provide a join only where a match occurs, so it does not remove rows from the naturally joined set. In this case you will get a list of all Users who are Field Reps, together with a count of their FRrequests with a 'Submitted' or 'Delayed' status if any.

COALESCE is used (in Postgresql at least) to check for a null value and then coerce it to the supplied value, in this case 0. So if a NULL value occurs (because, for instance, there was no 'Counter' value returned from the left outer join) it is replaced by 0.